# Jquery and HTML forms behaving differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

The following page has two forms, one is a simple upload form with no decoration and other one is a decorated form using the library of jquery-ui. When I click on submit button of the regular form the data perfectly gets submitted, I mean the uploaded file goes to the desired folder perfectly, but when I use trigger the submit function of other form using a click of a button then the servlet gets called but the same parameters dont get passed to the servlet. I mean there is nothing getting posted to the servlet when I submit using the decorated form.

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>

<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="open-form">Upload your file</div>
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Select your file">
        <form id="uploadForm" action="./uploadFile "
            enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="name"><b>Filepath</b></label> <input type="file"
                    class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="name" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>

    <form action="./uploadFile" enctype=" multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <div class="box2">
                Select your File</br> 
                <input type="file" name="Uploaded file"> 
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Upload">
        </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            var name = $("#name"), allFields = $([]).add(name);
            $("#dialog-form").dialog({
                autoOpen : false,
                height : 300,
                width : 460,
                modal : true,
                buttons : {
                    "Upload" : function() {
                        document.forms["uploadForm"].submit();
                    },
                    Cancel : function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close : function() {
                    allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
                }
            });
            $("#open-form").click(function() {

                $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");

            });

        });
    </script>

</body>
```

adding javascript in the tags just to be sure.
this is the servlet code:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
        try {           
            int formDataLength = req.getContentLength();
            byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
            DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            factory.setSizeThreshold(4096);
            factory.setRepository(new File("/location/y-folder"));
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            upload.setSizeMax(10000000);
            List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(req);           
            Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();
            FileItem fi = ((FileItem) i.next());
            InputStream inputStream = fi.getInputStream();
            String path = fi.getName();
            long h = fi.getSize();
            File f = new File("/location/x-folder"+path);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
            int len;
            while ((len = inputStream.read(dataBytes)) > 0) {
                out.write(dataBytes, 0, len);
            }
            out.close();
            inputStream.close();

            System.out.println("Fi:-" + fi.toString());
}catch(Exception e){
system.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: In the second form you're not closing the quote of the action. `action="./uploadFile enctype` should be `action="./uploadFile" enctype`

Comment: @Gabriel I am closing it in the actual code. I am sorry I actually edited the code.

Comment: What is Firebug saying? Can you check if the file gets send with the HTTP request in both case? I don't know how you access the form elements in your servlet but the id of the file is different in your two forms (`Uploaded file` and `name`). It would help if you could post your servlet code also.

Comment: @Gabriel I have uploaded my servlet as well. And in firebug the simple form sends the file in the post parameter. But the decorated form doesn't. It captures the value fine but when I submit the form only the simple one is able to read the file and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All input elements that need to be submitted to the server during form submission should ALWAYS have the `name` attribute.

Consider your code on the following line:

```
<label for="name"><b>Filepath</b></label> <input type="file"
     class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="name" />
```

and change it as follows:

```
<label for="name"><b>Filepath</b></label> <input type="file"
     class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="name"
     name="Uploaded file" />
```

Comment: I cant believe the solution was so simple. Thanks a lot. It saved me a lot of trouble. I appreciate it.